# nodejs - LDAP Client installation error (Windows XP machine)

Tags: node.js, ldap, windows-xp

When I'm trying to install LDAP Client on a Windows XP system, I'm getting an error.
Can any expert give guidelines/steps on how to run the LDAP client or even better how to get \node_modules for the LDAP client?

When tried: `npm install ldapjs`

```
ERR! error rolling back ldapjs@0.5.7 Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir 'C:\Documents and Settings\dilipkumar_s\node_modules\ldapjs'
ERR! Unsupported
ERR! Not compatible with your version of node/npm: pooling@0.3.2
ERR! Required: {"node":">=0.8"}
ERR! Actual:   {"npm":"1.1.16","node":"0.6.15"}
ERR! 
ERR! System Windows_NT 5.1.2600
ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "ldapjs"
ERR! cwd C:\Documents and Settings\dilipkumar_s
ERR! node -v v0.6.15
ERR! npm -v 1.1.16
ERR! code ENOTSUP
ERR! message Unsupported
ERR! errno {}
verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

1. When node is updated to version 8.0 getting an error for the python installation:

```
D:\work\node\newpoc\node_modules\ldapjs\node_modules\buffertools>node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-
bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at failNoPython (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:109:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:78:11
gyp ERR! stack     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:297:15)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
```

2. After python is installed its asking for VC++:

````
:\ExpressApps\node_modules\ldapjs\node_modules\dtrace-provider>node "C:\Program Files\node
s\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/abbrev
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find "msbuild.exe". Do you have Microsoft Visual Studio C++ 201
 installed?
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\bu
ld.js:129:20
gyp ERR! stack     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:297:15)```
````

Answer (score 0):

`Not compatible with your version of node/npm: pooling@0.3.2 ERR! Required: {"node":">=0.8"}` means, "You need a newer version of node.js, at least v0.8", whereas it looks like you're running v0.6.15. I suggest downloading and installing the latest stable version. Then `npm install ldapjs` should work.